# Connection was broken Jenkins Master Slave

Tags: jenkins, jnlp

[image]
Hi Team, I am new to Jenkins, can anyone help me with the below issue. I use agent.jar and jenkins-slave.jnlp file to make a connection between Master and Slave in Jenkins. But I see error in making a connection between them. As shown in below screenshot I trie to use the commands recomended in slave machine still its not helping. Any help would be appriciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to ping the master from slave with master ip and port to see if it is accesible

Comment: ping is good @hars34 I see ping is up

Comment: can u pls provide the steps used to configure the agent?